# What is the appropriate loop for this amortization formula?

Tags: c++, formula, amortization

I am trying to print out the variable *loan_Amt* when the monthly payment exceeds/is equal to the 30% amount that is found in the *monthly_payment* function. This is my first attempt at writing a c++ program with functions!

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string>
#include<iomanip>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;

double monthly_Payment (double amt_Amt)
{
    double r;
    r = ( amt_Amt/ 12) * 30/100;
    return (r);
}

    double interest_Calculate(double interest_Amt)
{
    double r;
    r = (interest_Amt * .010);
    return (r);
}

//double loan_Calculate()
//{
//int x = interest_Calculate(interest_Rate);
//double monthly = (loan_Amt * x) / (1 - pow(1.0 + i,-(12*30)));
//for (((int loan_Amt = 20000) * (x/12)) / pow(1.0 + i,-(12*30)); loan_Amt>0; loan_Amt++);

//}

int main()
{

double gross_Salary;
double interest_Rate;
int x;
int i;
double monthly;

std::cout << "Please enter your yearly gross salary:";
std::cin >> gross_Salary;

std::cout << "Please enter an interest rate:";
std::cin >> interest_Rate;
int z;
z = monthly_Payment (gross_Salary);
std::cout << "The target (30 percent of monthly salary) monthly payment range is:" << z;
for ( int loan_Amt = 0; loan_Amt <= 5000000; x++ ) {
    do {
    x = interest_Calculate(interest_Rate);
     monthly = (loan_Amt * x) / (1 - pow(1.0 + x,-(12*30)));
     std::cout << loan_Amt;
    } while (monthly >= z );
}

getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `for ( int loan_Amt = 0; loan_Amt <= 5000000; x++ )` This doesn't seem to make much sense. `loan_Amt` never changes.

Answer (score 0):

The for loop has problem, I think,

```
for ( int loan_Amt = 0; loan_Amt <= 5000000; x++ ) {
do {
x = interest_Calculate(interest_Rate);
 monthly = (loan_Amt * x) / (1 - pow(1.0 + x,-(12*30)));
 std::cout << loan_Amt;
} while (monthly >= z );
```

}

loan_Amt will never change its value, so this is an infinite loop.
This line in the do-while loop,

```
std::cout << loan_Amt;
```

will always print zero